# Decode protocol form float to byte

Tags: java

I have the code:

```
public float encode(byte val) {
    val = (byte) (val >> 3);
    val = (byte) (val & 0x1F);
    return (float) (val + 10) / 10.0f;
}
```

I want to revers it, i know that the first(LSB) bits is 100, i tried the code below, it wont work, please help.

```
   public byte decode(float val) {
            val *= 10.0f;
            val -= 10;
            int tmp = (int)val;
            byte tmp2 = (byte) (tmp << 3);
            tmp2= (byte) (tmp2 | 4);
            return tmp2;
            //4=100
}
```

These how i tested the methods:

```
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            protocol.encode(((float)i)/10);
            System.out.println((((float)i)/10) +", "+protocol.decode());
    }
```

The results is:

```
0.0, 3.2
0.1, 3.3
0.2, 3.4
0.3, 3.5
0.4, 3.6
0.5, 3.7
0.6, 3.8
0.7, 3.9
0.8, 4.0
0.9, 4.1
1.0, 1.0
........
```

From 1.0 to 4.1 i get correct values, after 4.1 wrong values.

```
4.1, 4.1
4.2, 1.0
4.3, 1.1
4.4, 1.2
4.5, 1.3
4.6, 1.4
```

Comment: You sure the first `encode` is right, you only have 7 bits plus a sign but you are discarding the lower 3 bits meaning you only have 4 bits.  What should the discarded 3 bit be set to?

Comment: I tested the `decode(encode(byte))` for all possible bytes with 100 LSB, it works perfectly. Do you make any additional transformations with your `float` value? Probably serialize/deserialize? Show us the complete code when it doesn't work. It's likely a rounding error.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey. I wrote the second method `decode`, the first one `encode` is code of some program. The result of  `decode` is wrong

Comment: @TagirValeev, I added the code

Comment: @J.Davied, what is `protocol.encode(float)` in your test code? You supplied the only `encode` method which accepts byte.

Comment: @TagirValeev.- It the first method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `decode` means transform protocol level data to application level, and `encode` means transform application data to transport level (e.g. [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)). You names methods opposite. Second, there is no sense test this method for more than 256 byte values, because byte has only 256 distinct values (you don't use 3 bits, so you can transmit only 2^5=32 different float values). Third, your test should check that incoming application data goes through transport protocol and restored to initial state. Please look at my code:

```
public static float decode(byte val) {
    val = (byte) (val >> 3);
    val = (byte) (val & 0x1F);
    return (float) (val + 10) / 10.0f;
}
public static byte encode(float val) {
    val *= 10.0f;
    val -= 10;
    int tmp = (int)val;
    byte tmp2 = (byte) (tmp << 3);
    return tmp2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = Byte.MIN_VALUE; i < Byte.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        float f =  decode((byte)i);
        System.out.printf("%s\t%s%n", f, decode(encode(f)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you expect the integer number after the multiplication, try to round your number:

```
public static byte decode(float val) {
    val = Math.round(val * 10.0f);
    val -= 10;
    ...
}
```

Probably the multiplication result appears to be just below the integer number (like `31.999999f` instead `32.0f`) due to lack of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float byteToFloat (byte byteVal) {
    final byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, byteVal }
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();
}

byte floatToByte (float floatVal) {
   final int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(floatVal);
   return (byte)(bits & 0xff);
}
```